# docker build : Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found

Tags: php, symfony, docker, memcached, dockerfile

I'm dockerizing a project made with symfony framework. following error occured.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Package operations: 28 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing twig/twig (v1.12.1): Cloning v1.12.1
    Failed to download twig/twig from source: Your configuration does not allow connections to git://github.com/fabpot/Twig.git. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
    Now trying to download from dist
  - Installing twig/twig (v1.12.1): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing doctrine/common (2.3.0): Cloning 2.3.0
  - Installing symfony/symfony (v2.1.7): Cloning v2.1.7
    Failed to download symfony/symfony from source: Your configuration does not allow connections to git://github.com/symfony/symfony.git. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
    Now trying to download from dist
  - Installing symfony/symfony (v2.1.7): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing jdorn/sql-formatter (v1.2.0): Cloning v1.2.0
    Failed to download jdorn/sql-formatter from source: Your configuration does not allow connections to git://github.com/jdorn/sql-formatter.git. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
    Now trying to download from dist
  - Installing jdorn/sql-formatter (v1.2.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing doctrine/dbal (2.3.2): Cloning 2.3.2
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (v1.1.0): Cloning v1.1.0
    Failed to download doctrine/doctrine-bundle from source: Your configuration does not allow connections to git://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle.git. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
    Now trying to download from dist
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (v1.1.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing doctrine/orm (2.3.2): Cloning 2.3.2
    Failed to download doctrine/orm from source: Your configuration does not allow connections to git://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
    Now trying to download from dist
  - Installing doctrine/orm (2.3.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle (1.1.2): Cloning 1.1.2
  - Installing jms/cg (1.0.0): Cloning 1.0.0
    Failed to download jms/cg from source: Your configuration does not allow connections to git://github.com/schmittjoh/cg-library.git. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
    Now trying to download from dist
  - Installing jms/cg (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing jms/metadata (1.1.1): Cloning 1.1.1
  - Installing jms/aop-bundle (1.0.0): Cloning 1.0.0
  - Installing jms/di-extra-bundle (1.1.1): Cloning 1.1.1
  - Installing jms/security-extra-bundle (1.2.0): Cloning 1.2.0
  - Installing kriswallsmith/assetic (dev-master 5591252): Cloning 5591252faa
    Failed to download kriswallsmith/assetic from source: Your configuration does not allow connections to http://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic.git. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
    Now trying to download from dist
  - Installing kriswallsmith/assetic (dev-master 5591252): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing phpoffice/phpexcel (1.7.9): Cloning 7a7634fba6
  - Installing irongit/symfony2-stream-response (dev-master 3e5082e): Cloning 3e5082e7be
  - Installing liuggio/excelbundle (v1.0.5): Cloning 9cf3e2ec21
  - Installing kriswallsmith/buzz (v0.10): Cloning 759432d663
  - Installing sensio/buzz-bundle (dev-master 929c883): Cloning 929c883f8d
  - Installing sensio/distribution-bundle (v2.1.7): Cloning v2.1.7
  - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v2.1.7): Cloning v2.1.7
  - Installing sensio/generator-bundle (v2.1.7): Cloning v2.1.7
  - Installing symfony/assetic-bundle (v2.1.0): Cloning v2.1.0-RC2
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.2.1): Cloning 1.2.1
  - Installing symfony/monolog-bundle (v2.1.7): Cloning v2.1.7
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v4.2.2): Cloning v4.2.2
    Failed to download swiftmailer/swiftmailer from source: Your configuration does not allow connections to git://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer.git. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
    Now trying to download from dist
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v4.2.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.1.7): Cloning v2.1.7
  - Installing twig/extensions (dev-master 5c2d515): Cloning 5c2d515d46
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/lessphp (Assetic provides the integration with the lessphp LESS compiler)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/scssphp (Assetic provides the integration with the scssphp SCSS compiler)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/scssphp-compass (Assetic provides the integration with the SCSS compass plugin)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing ptachoire/cssembed (Assetic provides the integration with phpcssembed to embed data uris)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing mlehner/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
Generating autoload files
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets

Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found in /var/www/html/gallery_core/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 497
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception


  [RuntimeException]                                                            
  An error occurred when executing the "'assets:install '\''web'\'''" command.
```

I searched for a while found this may be memcached in not properly installed. But here I'm using docker I've build a memcached service.

Memcached dockerfile:

```
FROM memcached:1.4-alpine

# Port to expose (default: 11211)
EXPOSE 11211

# Default Memcached run command arguments
CMD ["-m", "128"]

# Set the user to run Memcached daemon
USER daemon

# Set the entrypoint to memcached binary
ENTRYPOINT memcached
```

php Dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    unzip

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer --version


ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles
ENV SYMFONY_ENV='dev'
# RUN php composer.phar install --prefer-source

ENV docroot='/var/www/html'
ENV contentroot='/var/content'     


RUN mkdir $docroot/gallery_core
copy . $docroot/gallery_core/
copy php.ini /usr/local/etc/php

RUN cd $docroot/gallery_core

WORKDIR $docroot/gallery_core


RUN composer install --prefer-source

RUN cp $docroot/gallery_core/web/app_dev.php $docroot/gallery_core/web/app.php 

# install symfony symlinks
RUN php $docroot/gallery_core/app/console assets:install $docroot/gallery_core/web --symlink

# install a symlink for the assets:
RUN ln -s $docroot/gallery_core/web $docroot/gallery_core/web/gcassets
```

Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "irongit/symfony2-stream-response": "dev-master",
        "liuggio/excelbundle": ">=1.0.4",
        "sensio/buzz-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    }
}
```

My question is how to make the service that is running php script able to "detect" memcached service as the way memcached is directly installed on the host and transparent to php script service?

Comment: The problem is not in memcached itself. The problem is that your php has not the memcached php module, the package is usually `php5-memcached `

Comment: please post the docker file of the php-fpm service

Comment: Hi @Matteo, I have posted the php dockerfile, could you please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install **memcached** for docker (php-5.6) change

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    unzip
```

to

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y git unzip zlib1g-dev libmemcached11 libmemcached-dev \
    && yes '' | pecl install memcached-2.2.0 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached \
    && yes '' | pecl install memcache \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcache
```

and rebuild php container, this will install memcache and memcached extensions for php

Comment: Hi, after change to this it still failed:

No valid packages found
install failed
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y     git     unzip zlib1g-dev libmemcached11 libmemcached-dev     && yes '' | pecl install memcached     && docker-php-ext-enable memcached     && yes '' | pecl install memcache     && docker-php-ext-enable memcache' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: `memcached-2.2.0` ... and some more change

Comment: @frank no problem)